# Using cat command , why result is printed like that?

Tags: file-pointer

```
># cat /etc/passwd > test 
># cat < test >> test
```

I input in prompt like that.

Then result of the command is that size of test file increases a lot and quickly.
Why does that happen?

Comment: If you connect a camera to a TV to see what it is recording, and then point the camera at that TV, you get infinity, which is what happens here.

Answer (score 1):

In your second command, you're telling the OS to:

1. Open `test` for read (`< test`)
2. Open `test` for write, and seek to the end (`>> test`)

And then `cat` reads a chunk from the current read filepointer, and writes that chunk to the current write filepointer, until it reaches the end. However, because the file keeps growing with each write, the read chunk never hits the actual end, and it goes on forever.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you read and write to the same file (`"test"`). Apparently your computer is writing faster than it reads. Read doesn't get EOF (end of file) and therefore file grows.

It's an interesting case, on which device/filesystem type file "test" is created?

Comment: my home directory *^^*

Comment: i understand  a little !!